# How can I debug my user defined function program

Tags: java

I wrote a program, which had a logic error that I am unable to find. How can I find the cause of the error?

```
import java.util.*;
class D3Point {
    static double x,y,z;
    D3Point()
    {
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
        z=0.0;
    }
    static void acceptPoint()
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER THE X-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        x=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE Y-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        y=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE Z-COORDINATE OF THE POINT");
        z=sc.nextDouble();
    }
    static void displayPoint()
    {
        System.out.println("("+x+","+y+","+z+")");
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        D3Point Point1= new D3Point();
        D3Point Point2= new D3Point();
        Point1.acceptPoint();
        Point2.acceptPoint();
        System.out.println("THE COORDINATES OF THE TWO POINTS ARE:");
        Point1.displayPoint();
        Point2.displayPoint();
    } 
    }
```

This program was supposed to take in the coordinates of two points in 3D and print them, but for some reason the second input that I am giving for the object Point2 is also being assigned to the object Point1 and I do not know where I am wrong. What can I try next?

Comment: Tip: when posting a question involving a specific programming language, always use a tag for that language. It will help get your question in front of people who are most able to help.

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike languages such as C/C++, Java's entry point is a method that has the following fixed syntax:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

The required parameter indicates that the program accepts command-line arguments which you can access through the `args` array.
You can rename this parameter, but by convention, it is `args`.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs given at the first are **being overwritten** by the inputs that are provided in the second.

```
        D3Point Point1= new D3Point();
        D3Point Point2= new D3Point();
        Point1.acceptPoint();  
        Point2.acceptPoint(); // calling this method back to back is the cause of the problem.
```

To avoid this, **Try printing the values once you get it**. I've made few changes in your code to print the values of 1st and 2nd inputs.

```
public static void main(String[] ar)   // in the code you provided, main method doesnt have any arguments. So pls add that too in your program
{
    D3Point Point1= new D3Point();
    D3Point Point2= new D3Point();
    Point1.acceptPoint();     // gets the values
    System.out.println("THE COORDINATES OF THE TWO POINTS ARE:");
    Point1.displayPoint();  // prints the values
    Point2.acceptPoint();
    System.out.println("THE COORDINATES OF THE TWO POINTS ARE:");
    Point2.displayPoint();
}
```

And **To debug** your program, place a breakpoint in the methods that you use in the program and instead of running the program by clicking the play button you can debug the program by clicking the bug icon in your IDE or use the shortcut in eclipse Alt + Shift + D,J.